# Uncaught Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, user-interface, selectinput

I am trying to use rimble-ui Select input but getting error

```
Uncaught Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
```

source : https://rimble.consensys.design/components/rimble-ui/Select

codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-bartik-rrp1v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the select component in a `<Field/>`? As per the examples here: https://rimble.consensys.design/components/rimble-ui/Select

Comment: @Jayce444 Yes not working with Field wrapper updated please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an internal bug, downgrading to `0.11.1` will make it work.

[image: Edit competent-wozniak-dgqy4]